# Trouble in Layout design Android

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have created an Android Application in that I have problem in Layout design.

Please see layout in this link-

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/WJRLolp6PVoKskRBdFH6VMmdqftSgt10EZhd-A1h_glblYoJjVrF8bYjsPXmw752sGttlzIh7IHwtQo=w1342-h479

My code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/product_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/product" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/product_image"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/userimage" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Distance"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain a little bit more about the problem you are facing. And please post your layout xml file codes here. On the link you have provided, only image of the layout is there.

Comment: In the image you can see that the Product Image is ImageView and User Image is between Product Image and Texts (120 KM Away...), so how to manage this

Comment: post your xml....giving some negative padding/margin at the top of user image will do the trick

Comment: Now you can see my code

Comment: @Raghavendra Please see my code

Comment: @nKaushik Please see my code

Comment: @DroidMind Please see my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/user_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

change the user image xml to above code and try

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Relative layout for that

or

you can make it custom layout

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html